# Disable "Network" link from Internet Explorer file browser for a public Win 7 PC

Tags: windows, networking, group-policy, internet-explorer

I have followed this [guide](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/823777-in-windows-explorer-can-i-hide-favorites-libraries-and-desktop-with-a-gpo) to disable the "Network" link in **Windows Explorer** by changing a registry key and that is working. The link is gone from every application other than **Internet Explorer**'s save-as file browser. This is for a public library public access computer on our network, so this is bad. I have searched extensively online as well as through group policy options for Windows 7 and Internet Explorer, but haven't found a way to disable this link. Any suggestions?

Here is a screenshot of the link as it appears from Internet Explorer:
[image]

*EDIT*
I have tried the following GPOs to no avail. Both state they only work with older versions of Windows, so it is not surprising they didn't work.

- No Entire Network in Network Locations
- No Computers Near Me in    Network Locations

Answer (score 0):

finally found the answer. There are many guides similar to the one I linked to previously, but I found only one that mentions editing the same registry key for Software. Change the key from **b0040064** to **b0940064** and the Network link will be removed from Windows Explorer.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes\CLSID\{F02C1A0D-BE21-4350-88B0-7367FC96EF3C}\ShellFolder
```